Dying Hard disk has a profile folder, how to ensure succesful admin login?
Using Windows 7 64 bit.
I have a dying hard disk which contains all my windows 7 profiles, including the admin account. My windows OS is on another hard disk. I did this separation between OS and user folder initially during installation because I knew that my user folder is gonna be consuming a lot of space and becoming larger over time and I wanted to keep my Windows partition clean. I used the instruction here:
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124198-user-profiles-create-move-during-windows-7-installation.html?s=5a2d05f6863a139e9790bcf4223cb348
I am currently doing a backup of my dying disk. My goal is to buy a new hard disk and restore the user partition but here is the problem. Because the user profile is located in the bad disk, I fear that I would be unable to login to windows if had to restart the PC after connecting a new hard disk, since windows will not be able to find the user profile folder. I had a similar problem before where I couldn't login to windows and had to use the windows repair disk to point to a new path in registry to be able to login when my previous drive failed and the new disk was assigned a different letter.
What is the best way to solve this issue? I need access to admin privilege whilst doing the backup process. Could I just create a new admin profile, save it in my OS partition, edit the registry to make sure the path is correct, and login to the new account and make the backup from there? Is it possible to have multiple user profile folders on different partitions? I just need this profile to ensure backup process runs smoothly. And I need to ensure that I will not be locked out i.e. always able to login to an admin account.
Alternatively could I just copy my current admin profile folder(without the rest of the junk, not sure which folder to copy though) to the OS drive, edit registry path and login as usual?
I am still logged on this account (I only have one account) and I need to do this urgently whilst I still have access. I fear if I restart my PC I won't be able to do anything if the drive dies suddenly. Thank you very much for your help.

Make a complete drive image using fault-tolerant imaging tool, e.g., https://roadkil.net/program.php/P22/Raw Copy . Work with the copy, and even restore it to a new drive.
